# How to change the way tabs are displayed?

Tags: emacs, tabs

In Emacs, how can I display tabs like this?

[image: tab display in vim]

Some py files use tab keys,and sometimes it's very ugly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set how the tab character is displayed in a buffer by using `aset` on the `buffer-display-table`. An example would look something like this:

```
(aset buffer-display-table
      ?\t                        ;;Character to replace
      [?> ?- ?- ?- ?- ?- ?- ?-]) ;;Characters to replace with
```

If you want to specify a string instead (since it's a bit more readable), this is the shortest way I've found to do it (if anyone knows a better way to convert a string to a char vector, please let me know).

```
(aset buffer-display-table ?\t
      (map 'vector 'string-to-char 
           (split-string ">-------" "" t)))
```

You can undo this change by setting the value back to a tab character:

```
(aset buffer-display-table ?\t [?\t])
```

This only modified the current buffer, so you'd need to use a hook to call it when you enter python mode. Alternatively, you could use `standard-display-table` instead, which would replace it anywhere that doesn't have it's own display table.